# How to handle "Not Found" error in Web API Controller - Get Method, MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this API method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public MyTable GetMyTable(byte id, string langid)
    {
        MyTable mytable = db.MyTables.Find(id, langid);

        if (mytable  == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return mytable;
    }
```

Currently it throws NotFound exception, but I don't want it to throw exception, instead I want to get in JSON format message that the required entry it was not found.

I could add try/catch block with HttpResponseException but this method returns instance of the model, not HttpResponseMessage.

Note: I am using MVC 4, Visual Studio 2010, EntityFramework 4.3

What should I change in the method above?

P.S. Would it be better if I just return empty instance created with

```
myTable = db.MyTableDbSet.Create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using .NET 4.0 and Task.FromResult() was added in .NET 4.5, so I don't think I will be able to use IHttpActionResult interface.

Here is what I did:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetMyTable(string id, string langid)
    {
        MyTable myTable = db.MyTableDbSet.Find(id, langid);

        if (myTable == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myTable);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I find myself comfortable with this kind of approach:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetMyTable(byte id, string langid)
{
    var mytable = db.MyTables.Find(id, langid);

    if (mytable  != null)
    {
        return Ok(mytable);
    }
           
    return NotFound();
}
```

Comment: What packages do I need to include to use IHttpActionResult, and NotFound. It seems it cannot resolve those. I don't get Resolve option when I right click them?

Comment: using System.Web.Http;

Comment: Yes, I have System.Web.Http. I am using MVC 4, Visual Studio 2010, EntityFramework 4.3 It doesn't recognize it. It seems I am using older version of Web API?

Comment: You might need to translate the above syntax as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results). See *HttpResponseMessage* section.

Comment: Good article, but I guess I am using .NET 4.0 and Task.FromResult() was added in .NET 4.5, so I don't think I will be able to use IHttpActionResult interface. However, I can use HttpResponseMessage, but the problem is, when the data is not found, I just get null. What would be the right way to just return json message but empty one?

Comment: Why not returning an HttpResponseMessage as described in the article above?
Have you tried to change the return parameter to HttpResponseMessage  and replace Ok(mytable) with  **Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, mytable)** and
NotFound() with **Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)**